# É possível substituir uma div por outra em html?

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, gostaria de saber se tem como sobrepor ou trocar uma div por outra via javascript, pois estou fazendo um jogo que possui uma div que é  tela de home e outra que é a tela de seleção de personagens,e queria que quando um botão fosse pressionado a div home mudasse para a div de personagens, onde esta permanecesse  na mesma posição e ficasse com a mesma altura e largura que a anterior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui entender muito bem a sua pergunta.

**Exemplo em Jquery**

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('div#home').hide();
  $('div#personagens').show();
});
```

```css
#home {
  background:black;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#personagens {
  background:green;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="personagens"></div>
<button>MUDAR</button>
```

Comment: Pense nos quadrados como se fossem telas de um jogo, o primeiro é aquela tela que só tem o logo do jogo e um botão "jogar" sabe?A segunda tela já seria o jogo funcionando

Comment: posta seu código aqui, existem várias possibilidades